# How to use Tesseract PHP wrapper on wamp server

Tags: php, wamp, ocr, tesseract

I used composer to install this Tesseract PHP wrapper : `https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php`
by typing the following command line directly from my php project folder located at `C:/wamp/www/project_folder`:

```
$ composer require thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr
```

I created a php file called 'new' in the same folder where i try to use tesseract by typing :

```
use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;
echo (new TesseractOCR('text.png'))
->run();
```

I get the following error :

> Fatal error: Class 'thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR' not found
>   in C:\wamp\www\project_folder\new.php on line 4

Here's the content of my project folder :

```
   vendor(a folder)
   composer.json 
   composer.lock
   new.php 
   test.png
```

I have wampserver version 2.5
I have already installed tesseract (version 4) at C:program files
I included the following code to my php file in order to set the path but still encoutering the error.

```
$path = getenv('PATH');
putenv("PATH=$path:C:\Program Files\Tesseract_OCR");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `new.php` contain the include for `autoload.php`? You most probably have to add `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of that file

Comment: Yes I tried to include that line, and now my file looks like this : $path = getenv('PATH');
putenv("PATH=$path:C:\Program Files\Tesseract_OCR");
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;
echo (new TesseractOCR('text.png'))
->run(); which is giving another type of error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\wamp\www\tess\vendor\thiagoalessio\tesseract_ocr\src\TesseractOCR.php on line 49

Comment: Which version of that wrapper and which PHP version are you using?

Comment: version 5.5.12 of PHP and 2.0.0 for the wrapper as indicated in composer.json file

Comment: Version 2.0.0 uses features of PHP that are not available in versions before 5.6, so you either have to use an older version of the wrapper or update your PHP versions. The second option is preferable, as the security support for 5.5 has ended in July 2016

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try the second option and see what it gives.

Comment: I'm now using PHP 5.6. The script now runs with no errors. However, it doesn't return anything. The page is empty !

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by first using a newer version of PHP as Nico Haase suggested, and second putting my php file on the same path as the tesseract executable.